# How to check whether the Open/Save As dialog box is opened in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, process, system.diagnostics, user32

I have written a `vb.net` application to start an external application (**notepad.exe**) and then open the txt file located in at **"D:\test.txt"**.
I have used keyboard events to achive this.

**Step1:** Open the notepad

```
Process.Start("notepad.exe")
```

[image]

**Step 2:** Raised the keyboard event **Ctrl + O** to open the **Open** dialog box

```
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, &H45, 0, 0)
keybd_event(VK_O, 0, 0, 0)
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, &H45, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
```

**Step 3:** Wait for 2 seconds.

```
Thread.Sleep(2000)
```

**Step 4:** Raised the keyboard event to type the File path **"D:\Test.txt"** in the **File Name** textbox.
[image]

**Issue:** Occassionally the **Open** dialog box operation takes more time (exceeds 2000 ms) to open, as a result the file path typing event started before opening the open dialog box. I have increased the sleep time, but the issue not fixed completely.

[image]

Is there any way to check whether the **Open** dialog box is opened using the **notepad** process id?

I have tried using **[EnumChildWindows](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enumchildwindows)**, but i didn't get the result.

Comment: May I suggest `Process.Start("notepad.exe", "D:\test.txt")` as an alternative?

Comment: I have downvoted this as I can't see why it is useful to anyone else. If you want the user to edit text in your application you can do this using a textbox control

Comment: My original external application is not notepad. it is another product.

Answer (score 0):

The PID will change every time you open or close notepad. I would suggest to use the Image Name to check to see if it is open. beware of this option though because if you have to instances open this will cause an issue.

Comment: Still the other product will always have a different PID number as well